# Sealing a closet door that has a gas fired water heater in it

Tags: hvac, doors, sealing

Does anyone know how to make a self sealing door?

There's a bedroom in my basement, and it has a door in there that allows you access into the HVAC room (which can be entered from another door in the hallway) but this door is needed because you can directly access the tankless water heater, and you wouldn't be able to access it from the other door entrance.

I had an inspector tell me that this door must have an automatic closer, and self sealing.

I had a contractor look at it, and he wasn't entirely sure what to do.

Does anyone have any recommendations? The door is already solid core, and I Know you can buy self closing door hinges. But now I'm stuck trying to figure out how to make the door "sealed" all the way around so you don't have that tiny little gap of air that can come through.

Comment: What exactly does the inspector mean by "self sealing"  How sealed is sealed ? Did they explain  the purpose of having a "sealed" door. ???

Comment: Where does this tankless WH get its combustion air from? Specifically does it get it from outside the closet through a tube?

Comment: I assume it needs to be sealed because it's a gas appliance in a bedroom closet.

Comment: Yes, is this water heater a sealed combustion appliance?

Answer (score 1):

(Ensure there's adequate ventilation to the gas appliance even without the door before doing this.)

Put exterior-style weatherstripping in place. This includes the sides, top, and a threshold on the bottom. All of these should be available from your local hardware supply store and are DIY-level installs. I think this meets the requirements for sealing.